# How do I put Firefox add-on icons in the status bar?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Usually if I want a particular add-on button to show up in the bookmark toolbar instead of the menu toolbar, etc. I fire up Customize Toolbars and drag/drop the buttons.

Drag and drop clearly doesn't work for the status bar, though. Some add-ons have a status bar icon option, but is there an external solution that works for everything?

Comment: Probably worth noting that Firefox 4 will very probably allow you to just drag Add-On icons to the status bar (but may well get rid of the status bar totally if you don't have any icons using it) http://jboriss.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/removing-firefox%E2%80%99s-status-bar-and-rehousing-add-on-icons-part-2-of-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a Firefox Add-on enables the placement of an icon or control in the Firefox statusbar is determined by the Add-on itself. In other words, if the Add-on's developer has not made a statusbar icon or control part of the Add-on, there is nothing you can do through standard Firefox customization to change that.

Answer (score 1):

If someone ask a question like that in my opinion you should write how to reprogram that addon, to fit that particular icon there...

I'm searching for a solution like that in this moment. When usually I can't move something, and there is no native functionality for that, like how you wrote here. Then i usually ten to change the extension that way so that functionality would be included.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can have a status bar icon for an addon is if you downloaded the source, programmed it in, and installed it.  There is no native customization menu for the status bar in Firefox.